# Controlling Pandas plot layout

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am creating some plots and put them in one figure:

```
import pandas as pd

l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(l1)
l2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(l2)
l3 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(l3)
l4 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
df4 = pd.DataFrame(l4)
l5 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
df5 = pd.DataFrame(l5)
l6 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
df6 = pd.DataFrame(l6)
l7 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
df7 = pd.DataFrame(l7)
l8 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
df8 = pd.DataFrame(l8)
l9 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
df9 = pd.DataFrame(l9)
l10 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
df10 = pd.DataFrame(l10)
l11 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
df11 = pd.DataFrame(l11)

df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7,df8,df9,df10,df11], axis = 1)
df.plot(grid = 1,subplots = True, sharey = True)
```

Output:

[image: Fig1]

By modifying the code I can change the plot layout to this:

```
df.plot(grid = 1,subplots = True, layout = (6,5), sharey = True)
```

[image: Fig2]

or this:

```
df.plot(grid = 1,subplots = True, layout = (5,6), sharey = True)
```

[image: Fig3]

Is there a way to change the layout further? For these graphs this layout would be handy:

5/6 rows, 2 columns

```
IIIII IIIII
IIIII IIIII
IIIII IIIII
IIIII IIIII
IIIII IIIII
IIIII
```

Comment: `df.plot(grid = 1,subplots = True, layout = (6, 2), sharey = True)`.  You should note all that extra white empty space in your plots.  That's because you specified `(6, 5)` or six rows and 5 columns which is 30 subplots and most are empty.

Comment: I see, I tryied to plot with not enough "space" in the array. Now it works. thanks